# What is the best way to make a line between 2 span?

Tags: css, html

I have 2 span

```
<span style="float:left;">text1</span>
<span style="float:right;">text2</span>
```

How can I put a bottom line between the words? using css

Like _______________ this
and like ____________ this
and ____________ like this

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, you want a line between the `<span style="float:left;">text1</span>` and the `<span style="float:right;">text2</span>`?

Comment: Could you update your example to match your code? It would help with answering your question.

Comment: Why don't just a span in between with border-bottom, and a specified width using CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the nicest solution, but it works. It doesn't need a separate span element for the line, but it does use a container element per text line.

The black bottom line is created using a border on a pseudo-element on the left text. The line itself has full width, but the parts under the text are cancelled out because the texts themselves have a white border.

So disadvantages are that you need the container, it won't work well if you have an image background, and it probably won't work well if the two texts are larger than the available space on a line.

Nevertheless, I hope you can still use it.

```css
.line {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  
}
.left, 
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.left, 
.left::after {
  left: 0;
}

/* Left text is normal (not absolute), so it enforces the line to have the right hight (otherwise, multiple lines will fall on top of each other */
.right,
.left::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  padding-left: 0.5em; /* White space between bottomline and right text. */
}

.left {
  padding-right: 0.5em; /* White space between left text and bottom line */
}

.left::after {
  display: block;
  content: '\200B'; /* Any invisible character to enforce the right height. */
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  right: 0;
  z-index: -1; /* Pseudo element needs to be behind left text content */
}
```

```html
<span class='line'>
  <span class='left'>This is a text</span>
  <span class='right'>This as well</span>
</span>
<span class='line'>
  <span class='left'>Another</span>
  <span class='right'>Maybe a bit longer</span>
</span>
<span class='line'>
  <span class='left'>Short</span>
  <span class='right'>Text</span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution only works if you can allow for a container for each line that specifies the maximum width.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 80%; /* adapt this to your needs */
  clear: both;
}

.pull-left {
  float: left;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.pull-right {
  float: right;
  display: inline-flex;
  width: auto;
}

.pull-left::after {
  content: '\200B';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="pull-left">text1</span>
  <span class="pull-right">text2</span>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span class="pull-left">longertext3</span>
  <span class="pull-right">4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Would this work with a pseudo-element, so you wouldn't have to add a separate span for the black bottom line?

Comment: Managed to do it, and I used your "\200B", hadn't known about that before :)

Comment: Good. This way it's a relatively clean solution.

Answer (score 0):

I made everything `<div>`s then wrapped everything into a `<div class="wrap>` and then placed a `<div class="mid">` inbetween the first 2 `<div>`s left and right.
The line is `.mid`'s `border-bottom`. I assigned `display: table-cell` to `.left`, `.right`, and `.mid` and `.wrap`as a `table-row`. This table layout is used to ensure consistency but I wouldn't use it for large projects. Btw, this is responsive as well. You can stretch and shrink it as little or as much as possible and it's simple layout cannot break.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font: 400 32px/1.5'Source Code Pro';
}
.mid {
  padding: 0 0 -15% 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 60vw;
}
.wrap {
  display: table-row;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: -50%;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  width: 20vw;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: left;
}
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 20vw;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">

  <div class="left">text1</div>
  <div class="mid"></div>
  <div class="right">text2</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too sure if this is what you want, but I replaced the Underlines with Horizontal Rows between the Spans

```css
SPAN,
HR {
  FLOAT: LEFT;
}
HR {
  WIDTH: 100PX;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<BODY>

  <SPAN>Text 1</SPAN>
  <HR/>
  <SPAN>Text 2</SPAN>
  <BR/>
  <SPAN>Text 3</SPAN>
  <HR/>
  <SPAN>Text 4</SPAN>
  <BR/>
  <SPAN>Text 5</SPAN>
  <HR/>
  <SPAN>Text 6</SPAN>
  <BR/>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Comment: Doesn't work when the texts are not the same length.